# load .vimrc for gvim in windows and change font and colors

Tags: configuration, settings, vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [configure gvim setting color and font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136635/configure-gvim-setting-color-and-font)

Hi. I have just installed vim and want to set some default settings. I have installed gvim here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73`

I have my config file here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\.vimrc`

I just tried a config file I found. Here is the content of my current .vimrc

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Maintainer: amix the lucky stiff
"             http://amix.dk - amix@amix.dk
"
" Version: 3.6 - 25/08/10 14:40:30
"
" Blog_post: 
"       http://amix.dk/blog/post/19486#The-ultimate-vim-configuration-vimrc
" Syntax_highlighted:
"       http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.html
" Raw_version: 
"       http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.txt
"
" How_to_Install_on_Unix:
"    $ mkdir ~/.vim_runtime
"    $ svn co svn://orangoo.com/vim ~/.vim_runtime
"    $ cat ~/.vim_runtime/install.sh
"    $ sh ~/.vim_runtime/install.sh <system>
"      <sytem> can be `mac`, `linux` or `windows`
"
" How_to_Upgrade:
"    $ svn update ~/.vim_runtime
"
" Sections:
"    -> General
"    -> VIM user interface
"    -> Colors and Fonts
"    -> Files and backups
"    -> Text, tab and indent related
"    -> Visual mode related
"    -> Command mode related
"    -> Moving around, tabs and buffers
"    -> Statusline
"    -> Parenthesis/bracket expanding
"    -> General Abbrevs
"    -> Editing mappings
"
"    -> Cope
"    -> Minibuffer plugin
"    -> Omni complete functions
"    -> Python section
"    -> JavaScript section
"
"
" Plugins_Included:
"     > minibufexpl.vim - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159
"       Makes it easy to get an overview of buffers:
"           info -> :e ~/.vim_runtime/plugin/minibufexpl.vim
"
"     > bufexplorer - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42
"       Makes it easy to switch between buffers:
"           info -> :help bufExplorer
"
"     > yankring.vim - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1234
"       Emacs's killring, useful when using the clipboard:
"           info -> :help yankring
"
"     > surround.vim - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697
"       Makes it easy to work with surrounding text:
"           info -> :help surround
"
"     > snipMate.vim - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540
"       Snippets for many languages (similar to TextMate's):
"           info -> :help snipMate
"
"     > mru.vim - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=521
"       Plugin to manage Most Recently Used (MRU) files:
"           info -> :e ~/.vim_runtime/plugin/mru.vim
"
"     > Command-T - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025
"       Command-T plug-in provides an extremely fast, intuitive mechanism for opening filesa:
"           info -> :help CommandT
"           screencast and web-help -> http://amix.dk/blog/post/19501
"
"
"  Revisions:
"     > 3.6: Added lots of stuff (colors, Command-T, Vim 7.3 persistent undo etc.)
"     > 3.5: Paste mode is now shown in status line  if you are in paste mode
"     > 3.4: Added mru.vim
"     > 3.3: Added syntax highlighting for Mako mako.vim 
"     > 3.2: Turned on python_highlight_all for better syntax
"            highlighting for Python
"     > 3.1: Added revisions ;) and bufexplorer.vim
"
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => General
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Sets how many lines of history VIM has to remember
set history=700

" Enable filetype plugin
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

" Set to auto read when a file is changed from the outside
set autoread

" With a map leader it's possible to do extra key combinations
" like <leader>w saves the current file
let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","

" Fast saving
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>

" Fast editing of the .vimrc
map <leader>e :e! ~/.vim_runtime/vimrc<cr>

" When vimrc is edited, reload it
autocmd! bufwritepost vimrc source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrc


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => VIM user interface
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Set 7 lines to the curors - when moving vertical..
set so=7

set wildmenu "Turn on WiLd menu

set ruler "Always show current position

set cmdheight=2 "The commandbar height

set hid "Change buffer - without saving

" Set backspace config
set backspace=eol,start,indent
set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l

set ignorecase "Ignore case when searching
set smartcase

set hlsearch "Highlight search things

set incsearch "Make search act like search in modern browsers
set nolazyredraw "Don't redraw while executing macros 

set magic "Set magic on, for regular expressions

set showmatch "Show matching bracets when text indicator is over them
set mat=2 "How many tenths of a second to blink

" No sound on errors
set noerrorbells
set novisualbell
set t_vb=
set tm=500


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Colors and Fonts
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
syntax enable "Enable syntax hl

" Set font according to system
if MySys() == "mac"
  set gfn=Menlo:h14
  set shell=/bin/bash
elseif MySys() == "windows"
  set gfn=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono:h10
elseif MySys() == "linux"
  set gfn=Monospace\ 10
  set shell=/bin/bash
endif

if has("gui_running")
  set guioptions-=T
  set t_Co=256
  set background=dark
  colorscheme peaksea
  set nonu
else
  colorscheme zellner
  set background=dark

  set nonu
endif

set encoding=utf8
try
    lang en_US
catch
endtry

set ffs=unix,dos,mac "Default file types


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Files, backups and undo
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Turn backup off, since most stuff is in SVN, git anyway...
set nobackup
set nowb
set noswapfile

"Persistent undo
try
    if MySys() == "windows"
      set undodir=C:\Windows\Temp
    else
      set undodir=~/.vim_runtime/undodir
    endif

    set undofile
catch
endtry


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Text, tab and indent related
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set smarttab

set lbr
set tw=500

set ai "Auto indent
set si "Smart indet
set wrap "Wrap lines


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Visual mode related
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Really useful!
"  In visual mode when you press * or # to search for the current selection
vnoremap <silent> * :call VisualSearch('f')<CR>
vnoremap <silent> # :call VisualSearch('b')<CR>

" When you press gv you vimgrep after the selected text
vnoremap <silent> gv :call VisualSearch('gv')<CR>
map <leader>g :vimgrep // **/*.<left><left><left><left><left><left><left>


function! CmdLine(str)
    exe "menu Foo.Bar :" . a:str
    emenu Foo.Bar
    unmenu Foo
endfunction 

" From an idea by Michael Naumann
function! VisualSearch(direction) range
    let l:saved_reg = @"
    execute "normal! vgvy"

    let l:pattern = escape(@", '\\/.*$^~[]')
    let l:pattern = substitute(l:pattern, "\n$", "", "")

    if a:direction == 'b'
        execute "normal ?" . l:pattern . "^M"
    elseif a:direction == 'gv'
        call CmdLine("vimgrep " . '/'. l:pattern . '/' . ' **/*.')
    elseif a:direction == 'f'
        execute "normal /" . l:pattern . "^M"
    endif

    let @/ = l:pattern
    let @" = l:saved_reg
endfunction



"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Command mode related
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Smart mappings on the command line
cno $h e ~/
cno $d e ~/Desktop/
cno $j e ./
cno $c e <C-\>eCurrentFileDir("e")<cr>

" $q is super useful when browsing on the command line
cno $q <C-\>eDeleteTillSlash()<cr>

" Bash like keys for the command line
cnoremap <C-A>      <Home>
cnoremap <C-E>      <End>
cnoremap <C-K>      <C-U>

cnoremap <C-P> <Up>
cnoremap <C-N> <Down>

" Useful on some European keyboards
map Â½ $
imap Â½ $
vmap Â½ $
cmap Â½ $


func! Cwd()
  let cwd = getcwd()
  return "e " . cwd 
endfunc

func! DeleteTillSlash()
  let g:cmd = getcmdline()
  if MySys() == "linux" || MySys() == "mac"
    let g:cmd_edited = substitute(g:cmd, "\\(.*\[/\]\\).*", "\\1", "")
  else
    let g:cmd_edited = substitute(g:cmd, "\\(.*\[\\\\]\\).*", "\\1", "")
  endif
  if g:cmd == g:cmd_edited
    if MySys() == "linux" || MySys() == "mac"
      let g:cmd_edited = substitute(g:cmd, "\\(.*\[/\]\\).*/", "\\1", "")
    else
      let g:cmd_edited = substitute(g:cmd, "\\(.*\[\\\\\]\\).*\[\\\\\]", "\\1", "")
    endif
  endif   
  return g:cmd_edited
endfunc

func! CurrentFileDir(cmd)
  return a:cmd . " " . expand("%:p:h") . "/"
endfunc


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Moving around, tabs and buffers
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Map space to / (search) and c-space to ? (backgwards search)
map <space> /
map <c-space> ?
map <silent> <leader><cr> :noh<cr>

" Smart way to move btw. windows
map <C-j> <C-W>j
map <C-k> <C-W>k
map <C-h> <C-W>h
map <C-l> <C-W>l

" Close the current buffer
map <leader>bd :Bclose<cr>

" Close all the buffers
map <leader>ba :1,300 bd!<cr>

" Use the arrows to something usefull
map <right> :bn<cr>
map <left> :bp<cr>

" Tab configuration
map <leader>tn :tabnew<cr>
map <leader>te :tabedit 
map <leader>tc :tabclose<cr>
map <leader>tm :tabmove 

" When pressing <leader>cd switch to the directory of the open buffer
map <leader>cd :cd %:p:h<cr>


command! Bclose call <SID>BufcloseCloseIt()
function! <SID>BufcloseCloseIt()
   let l:currentBufNum = bufnr("%")
   let l:alternateBufNum = bufnr("#")

   if buflisted(l:alternateBufNum)
     buffer #
   else
     bnext
   endif

   if bufnr("%") == l:currentBufNum
     new
   endif

   if buflisted(l:currentBufNum)
     execute("bdelete! ".l:currentBufNum)
   endif
endfunction

" Specify the behavior when switching between buffers 
try
  set switchbuf=usetab
  set stal=2
catch
endtry


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Statusline
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Always hide the statusline
set laststatus=2

" Format the statusline
set statusline=\ %{HasPaste()}%F%m%r%h\ %w\ \ CWD:\ %r%{CurDir()}%h\ \ \ Line:\ %l/%L:%c


function! CurDir()
    let curdir = substitute(getcwd(), '/Users/amir/', "~/", "g")
    return curdir
endfunction

function! HasPaste()
    if &paste
        return 'PASTE MODE  '
    else
        return ''
    endif
endfunction


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Parenthesis/bracket expanding
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
vnoremap $1 <esc>`>a)<esc>`<i(<esc>
vnoremap $2 <esc>`>a]<esc>`<i[<esc>
vnoremap $3 <esc>`>a}<esc>`<i{<esc>
vnoremap $$ <esc>`>a"<esc>`<i"<esc>
vnoremap $q <esc>`>a'<esc>`<i'<esc>
vnoremap $e <esc>`>a"<esc>`<i"<esc>

" Map auto complete of (, ", ', [
inoremap $1 ()<esc>i
inoremap $2 []<esc>i
inoremap $3 {}<esc>i
inoremap $4 {<esc>o}<esc>O
inoremap $q ''<esc>i
inoremap $e ""<esc>i
inoremap $t <><esc>i


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => General Abbrevs
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
iab xdate <c-r>=strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")<cr>


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Editing mappings
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"Remap VIM 0
map 0 ^

"Move a line of text using ALT+[jk] or Comamnd+[jk] on mac
nmap <M-j> mz:m+<cr>`z
nmap <M-k> mz:m-2<cr>`z
vmap <M-j> :m'>+<cr>`<my`>mzgv`yo`z
vmap <M-k> :m'<-2<cr>`>my`<mzgv`yo`z

if MySys() == "mac"
  nmap <D-j> <M-j>
  nmap <D-k> <M-k>
  vmap <D-j> <M-j>
  vmap <D-k> <M-k>
endif

"Delete trailing white space, useful for Python ;)
func! DeleteTrailingWS()
  exe "normal mz"
  %s/\s\+$//ge
  exe "normal `z"
endfunc
autocmd BufWrite *.py :call DeleteTrailingWS()

set guitablabel=%t


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Cope
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Do :help cope if you are unsure what cope is. It's super useful!
map <leader>cc :botright cope<cr>
map <leader>n :cn<cr>
map <leader>p :cp<cr>


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => bufExplorer plugin
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let g:bufExplorerDefaultHelp=0
let g:bufExplorerShowRelativePath=1
map <leader>o :BufExplorer<cr>


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Minibuffer plugin
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 1
let g:miniBufExplorerMoreThanOne = 2
let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 0
let g:miniBufExplUseSingleClick = 1
let g:miniBufExplMapWindowNavVim = 1
let g:miniBufExplVSplit = 25
let g:miniBufExplSplitBelow=1

let g:bufExplorerSortBy = "name"

autocmd BufRead,BufNew :call UMiniBufExplorer

map <leader>u :TMiniBufExplorer<cr>


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Omni complete functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Spell checking
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"Pressing ,ss will toggle and untoggle spell checking
map <leader>ss :setlocal spell!<cr>

"Shortcuts using <leader>
map <leader>sn ]s
map <leader>sp [s
map <leader>sa zg
map <leader>s? z=


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Python section
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let python_highlight_all = 1
au FileType python syn keyword pythonDecorator True None False self

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.jinja set syntax=htmljinja
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.mako set ft=mako

au FileType python inoremap <buffer> $r return 
au FileType python inoremap <buffer> $i import 
au FileType python inoremap <buffer> $p print 
au FileType python inoremap <buffer> $f #--- PH ----------------------------------------------<esc>FP2xi
au FileType python map <buffer> <leader>1 /class 
au FileType python map <buffer> <leader>2 /def 
au FileType python map <buffer> <leader>C ?class 
au FileType python map <buffer> <leader>D ?def 


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => JavaScript section
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
au FileType javascript call JavaScriptFold()
au FileType javascript setl fen
au FileType javascript setl nocindent

au FileType javascript imap <c-t> AJS.log();<esc>hi
au FileType javascript imap <c-a> alert();<esc>hi

au FileType javascript inoremap <buffer> $r return 
au FileType javascript inoremap <buffer> $f //--- PH ----------------------------------------------<esc>FP2xi

function! JavaScriptFold() 
    setl foldmethod=syntax
    setl foldlevelstart=1
    syn region foldBraces start=/{/ end=/}/ transparent fold keepend extend

    function! FoldText()
    return substitute(getline(v:foldstart), '{.*', '{...}', '')
    endfunction
    setl foldtext=FoldText()
endfunction


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => MRU plugin
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let MRU_Max_Entries = 400
map <leader>f :MRU<CR>


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Command-T
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let g:CommandTMaxHeight = 15
set wildignore+=*.o,*.obj,.git,*.pyc
noremap <leader>j :CommandT<cr>
noremap <leader>y :CommandTFlush<cr>


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Vim grep
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let Grep_Skip_Dirs = 'RCS CVS SCCS .svn generated'
set grepprg=/bin/grep\ -nH



"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => MISC
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Remove the Windows ^M - when the encodings gets messed up
noremap <Leader>m mmHmt:%s/<C-V><cr>//ge<cr>'tzt'm

"Quickly open a buffer for scripbble
map <leader>q :e ~/buffer<cr>
au BufRead,BufNewFile ~/buffer iab <buffer> xh1 ===========================================

map <leader>pp :setlocal paste!<cr>

map <leader>bb :cd ..<cr>
```

From what I understand this should change the default colors

```
if has("gui_running")
  set guioptions-=T
  set t_Co=256
  set background=dark
  colorscheme peaksea
  set nonu
else
  colorscheme zellner
  set background=dark

  set nonu
endif
```

I have added `peaksea` and it works when I manually change the colors, but I want this to happen automatically. Clearly this does not happen... What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a first advise: since you're a starter with VIM, don't go and copy a `.vimrc` you find anywhere on the net. They could change the behavior of VIM in a way where nobody can help you if you experience any problems (and don't understand what's going on in your `.vimrc`).

In general, the settings specific for a GUI version (i.e. `GVim`) are stored in a separate file called `_gvimrc`. The default locations for `_vimrc` (yes, with underscore, not a dot under Win32) and `_gvimrc` is `C:/Documents and Settings/your_home_folder`. Plugins and colorschemes and any other stuff you install should go to a folder called `vimfiles` on the same location.

Using `_vimrc` for general settings and `_gvimrc` for GUI related settings, you avoid the

```
if has("gui_running")
  something
else
  something else
endif
```

blocks cluttering up your `_vimrc`. The `_vimrc` is getting sourced every time a new instance of Vim is started, afterwards, the `_gvimrc` gets sourced if it's a GVim.

Answer (score 4):

Use `:version` command to find the path of vimrc files.